# Which version of Kibana will be applicable for ElasticSearch 2.4.5?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

As i can't find kibana 2.4.5 in elastic.co/downloads.

My problem can be better described in attachment below-
[localhost:5601](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OPLG.png)

[elastic.co kibana2.4.5 not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBLrs.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kibana and ES did not have the same versioning before 5.x. So for ES 2.x you need a Kibana from the 4.x series. Unless you have a good reason not to pick the most recent of both with that major version. So Kibana 4.6.4 should be the right version for you. The 4.6 documentation lists elasticsearch 2.4 or later as the minimum version for this; so that matches what you have.